# Automatic PAC detection for smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib, pac

I'm trying to send an email with a Python 3.5 script, from a laptop that is connected to the internet through a PAC file. Is there a way of using [PyPAC](https://pypi.org/project/pypac/) for this?

With `requests`, this already works like a charm.

```
from pypac import PACSession
session = PACSession()
session.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Is there a way to somehow use a `PACSession` (or an equivalent) for `smtplib`?

```
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```